# Put list of log4j loggers into StringBuilder and format

Tags: java, log4j, stringbuilder

I am trying to add all `log4j` loggers into a list which needs to be put into `StringBuilder`. My method looks as follows:

```
    private void addLoggerInfo(StringBuilder sb) {

    LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    Map<String, LoggerConfig> loggers = ctx.getConfiguration().getLoggers();

    for (Iterator<String> iterator = loggers.keySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        String key = iterator.next();
        LoggerConfig cfg = loggers.get(key);
        String message = String.format("Logger for key %s : name: %s level: %s" , key,cfg.getName(), cfg.getLevel());
        LOG.info(message);
    }
//Need to put the list into StringBuilder
}
```

Question is how can the above code introduce `StringBuilder` to it and format the log statement in a specific format

`([[name=XXX | level=YYY], [name=XXX | level=YYY]])` than bunch of messages.

Limitations: Working with a huge code base and with only .0001% knowledge of the code. Doing small bits I am trying to understand the code base. The task is to log the loggers and print it in a nice format.

Comment: Is it actually log4j or log4j2 ?

Comment: @Fildor It's `log4j`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `LOG.info(message);` do `sb.append("[").append(message).append("]");`

Then log `sb.toString()` in the caller of `addLoggerInfo(sb)`.